# Getting the current user in SQL Server stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, active-directory

I have a SQL Server 2008 Express R2 instance authenticating from Active Directory. Users have records associated with their AD account stored in a database. I would like to have stored procedures for them to retrieve their records.

So the procedure might make the query `SELECT * FROM PurchaseOrders WHERE uid = $userid`

How do I find out `$userid`, a property in their AD profile?

Thanks!

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa172599%28v=sql.80%29.aspx

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Typically, you'd want to get the

```
SELECT SUSER_NAME()
```

from SQL Server - that's the connected user in `DOMAIN\UserName` format.

You don't typically have direct access to AD from a SQL Server machine to grab some bits from there.... if you can't work with the `DOMAIN\User Name` value, your best bet would be to pass in that information from your calling application to your stored procedure.

Comment: can we reveal the password also this way?

Comment: @Sunny: NO, you cannot reveal the password

Comment: Moreover even passing usernames as a parameter would allow to perform the operations on behalf of another person. Which is very bad!

Comment: @reubenjohn - No it would not. How could you do this?

Comment: @Robino My mistake I was assuming that 'parameters' here was referring to REST parameters which are sent over a network.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT * FROM PurchaseOrders WHERE uid = CURRENT_USER
```

or

```
SELECT * FROM PurchaseOrders WHERE uid = SUSER_NAME()
```